# Catch server response and display it to the screen angular/c#

Tags: c#, angular, http, client-server

I am making a client/server application. When the request has been successfully received by the server it sends back "Received" to the client. The word "Received" is currently being sent to the console but I would like to display the word sent by the server on the webpage. Is there a way to grab this response and display it on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the angular service, sendDetails can actually return Observable (since in C# you always return a string response).
Then, in angular component, when you subscribe, the 'success' param is already the string from C#.